# Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status)

Tags: node.js, next.js

Node 12.0.0 crashes on Windows 10 x64 (build 17134) when I try to launch next.js(:

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
#
#
#
error Command failed with exit code 3221225477.
```

I rollback to node 11.14.0 and it works properly.

Is there a fix or it's just a bug which will patched soon?

Comment: Err... context? define `any scripts`, what OS version? On what node version is the error happening?

Comment: Same here after upgrading to 12

Comment: Same here, also after upgrading to node 12. Rollbacking to any other version works.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error today running on:

- Ubuntu 18
- create-react-app 4.0.3
- Node v12.0

I solved it by upgrading Node to v12.18.0. I use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md) to manage my node versions.